# MySQL One to Many remove specific 'many'

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a one to many relationship (venues, with associated categories) like so:

```
venue_id | venue_name
---------------------
1        | venue1
2        | venue2
```

and categories

```
venue_id | category_id
---------------------
1        | 5
2        | 7
1        | 8
2        | 5
```

I want to show all venues that HAVE `category_id` of 5, but dont have `category_id` of 7 and 8. I tried using a join like so:

```
SELECT distinct(`venue_to_category`.`venue_id`),`venue_name` 
FROM `venue_to_category` INNER JOIN `venues` 
    ON `venues`.venue_id = `venue_to_category`.venue_id 
WHERE `category_id` != 7
AND `category_id` != 8 
AND `category_id` = 5
```

But it is not returning the correct results (in fact I am unsure the results it is returning)

Comment: You should state more clearly, what your expected result should look like. Do you want venues of category 5, venues of category 5 that are not in category 7 or category 8, or venues of category 5 that are in category 7 or 8, but not in both at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

2 Things in your case

1. Get data where category_id = 5 and not 7 or 8
2. Get data where category_id = 5 and not both 7 and 8

For the first one you can use

```
select
v.venue_id,
v.venue_name
from venues v
join categories c on c.venue_id = v.venue_id
where c.category_id = 5
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  select 1 from categories c1 where v.venue_id = c1.venue_id
  AND c1.category_id in (7,8)
);
```

For the 2nd one

```
select
v.venue_id,
v.venue_name
from venues v
join categories c on c.venue_id = v.venue_id
where c.category_id = 5
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  select 1 from categories c1 where v.venue_id = c1.venue_id
  AND c1.category_id in (7,8) having count(*) = 2
);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f529/2)**

Answer (score 0):

When doing a search function of your site. Match and Against is better than Like sql statement. The field must be set to FullText match the term on the field:

```
SELECT vc.venue_id, venue_name FROM venue_to_category vc, venues v WHERE MATCH(category_id) AGAINST('-7 -8 +5');
```

You can also use the IN BOOLEAN MODE to allow operators in the sql statement. eg. ...

MATCH(category_id) AGAINST('-7 -8 +5' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ...

(-) minus sign that means nothing should match '-7' '-8'

(+) the word must be present in the match.

There are many other operators to be used. Refer to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for more operator and explanation

Comment: That will still return venues with categories of 7 and 8, `x != 7` AND `x = 5` is the same as `x = 5`. Also MATCH is inappropriate here.

Comment: Did u tried running this query. Please do check @Arth

Comment: I don't need to MATCH is row by row, how can one row check all the categories?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
SELECT distinct `venue_to_category`.`venue_id` ,`venue_name`
FROM `venue_to_category` INNER JOIN `venues` 
    ON `venues`.venue_id = `venue_to_category`.venue_id 
WHERE `category_id` <> 7
AND `category_id` <> 8 
AND `category_id` = 5
```

or

```
SELECT distinct `venue_to_category`.`venue_id` ,`venue_name`
FROM `venue_to_category` INNER JOIN `venues` 
    ON `venues`.venue_id = `venue_to_category`.venue_id 
WHERE `category_id` NOT IN (7,8)
AND `category_id` = 5
```

Note: `distinct` is not a function. And for your example you could leave it out entirely, because there are no duplicate rows.

Comment: That will still return venues with categories of 7 and 8, `x != 7 AND x = 5` is the same as `x = 5`.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT v.id, v.name
  FROM venues v
  JOIN venue_to_category vc
    ON vc.venue_id=v.id
   AND vc.category_id=5
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM venue_to_category vci
     WHERE vci.venue_id = v.id
       AND vci.category_id IN (7,8)  
       );
```

Comment: @MohitShrivastava Kindly elaborate, even MySQL gives you more information than that.

Comment: Kindly create a SQL fiddle and check .. I tried to even change the names and tried hard to run your query but was not able to.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, Fixed it again!

Comment: @MohitShrivastava, Really have fixed it this time, check [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1fce/3)